# grub version and kernel version also are autonomously upgraded when ubuntu version is upgraded?

Tags: grub2, upgrade, kernel

Upgrading the ubuntu version has many challenges. I want to know whether kernel and grub versions are autonomously upgraded when upgrading the ubuntu version, ignoring those upgrade difficulties.

ubuntu uprade Examples :

16.04 -> 18.04

18.04 -> 20.04

16.04 -> 18.04 -> 20.04

Comment: Why not look; eg. https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=grub2 will show the grub version for many releases and show what will upgrade (*terminal enquiries will show more releases than the link I provided too*)

Comment: @
guiverc
I looked this site, too. But, I wander the case that after installing the ubuntu, the version is directly upgraded, no any installation. I think that it is not explicit. Besides, there is no 16 version on this site. On the old page, the grub part doesn't seem to be specified.

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04 LTS has ended it's *standard* (public/free) supported life (https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2021/03/13/extended-security-maintenance-for-ubuntu-16-04-xenial-xerus-begins-april-30-2021/) which is why it doesn't show, a CLI enquiry however will show it.  Those packages show what is installed on a new install, what you get when upgrading (the -updates link) for each release; which includes of course *release-upgrades*, ie. moving from 18.04 (*bionic*) to 20.04 (*focal*) will cause your packages to upgrade to the *focal-updates* version as per that page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Online you can find versions using https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=grub2 for `grub2` which show the versions for each release.

Using a command line enquiry I get even more results

```
 grub2 | 2.02~beta2-9            | trusty                   | source
 grub2 | 2.02~beta2-9            | trusty/universe          | amd64, i386, powerpc, ppc64el
 grub2 | 2.02~beta2-9ubuntu1.6   | trusty-security          | source
 grub2 | 2.02~beta2-9ubuntu1.6   | trusty-security/universe | amd64, i386, powerpc, ppc64el
 grub2 | 2.02~beta2-9ubuntu1.17  | trusty-updates           | source
 grub2 | 2.02~beta2-9ubuntu1.17  | trusty-updates/universe  | amd64, i386, powerpc, ppc64el
 grub2 | 2.02~beta2-36ubuntu3    | xenial                   | source                                                                       
 grub2 | 2.02~beta2-36ubuntu3    | xenial/universe          | amd64, i386, powerpc, ppc64el                                                
 grub2 | 2.02~beta2-36ubuntu3.27 | xenial-security          | source                                                                       
 grub2 | 2.02~beta2-36ubuntu3.27 | xenial-security/universe | amd64, i386, powerpc, ppc64el                                                
 grub2 | 2.02~beta2-36ubuntu3.32 | xenial-updates           | source
 grub2 | 2.02~beta2-36ubuntu3.32 | xenial-updates/universe  | amd64, i386, powerpc, ppc64el
 grub2 | 2.02-2ubuntu8           | bionic                   | source
 grub2 | 2.02-2ubuntu8           | bionic/universe          | amd64, i386, ppc64el
 grub2 | 2.02-2ubuntu8.25        | bionic-security          | source
 grub2 | 2.02-2ubuntu8.25        | bionic-security/universe | amd64, i386, ppc64el
 grub2 | 2.02-2ubuntu8.25        | bionic-updates           | source
 grub2 | 2.02-2ubuntu8.25        | bionic-updates/universe  | amd64, i386, ppc64el
 grub2 | 2.04-1ubuntu26          | focal                    | source
 grub2 | 2.04-1ubuntu26          | focal/universe           | amd64, ppc64el
 grub2 | 2.04-1ubuntu26.12       | focal-security           | source
 grub2 | 2.04-1ubuntu26.12       | focal-security/universe  | amd64, ppc64el
 grub2 | 2.04-1ubuntu26.15       | focal-updates            | source
 grub2 | 2.04-1ubuntu26.15       | focal-updates/universe   | amd64, ppc64el
 grub2 | 2.06-2ubuntu7           | jammy                    | source
 grub2 | 2.06-2ubuntu7           | jammy/universe           | amd64, ppc64el
 grub2 | 2.06-2ubuntu12          | kinetic                  | source
 grub2 | 2.06-2ubuntu12          | kinetic/universe         | amd64, ppc64el
 grub2 | 2.06-2ubuntu15          | lunar                    | source
 grub2 | 2.06-2ubuntu15          | lunar/universe           | amd64, ppc64el
```

Ubuntu 16.04 LTS has ended it's *standard* (public/free) supported life (https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2021/03/13/extended-security-maintenance-for-ubuntu-16-04-xenial-xerus-begins-april-30-2021/) which is why it doesn't show on the online enquiry (it does from terminal as it's still got ESM or extended support if you have ESM *enabled*).

Those packages show what is installed on a new install, what you get when upgrading (the -updates link) for each release; which includes of course *release-upgrades*, ie. moving from 18.04 (*bionic*) to 20.04 (*focal*) will cause your packages to upgrade to the *focal-updates* version as per that page.

If you install Ubuntu 18.04 LTS using initial media, the version I'd expect is

`grub2 | 2.02-2ubuntu8           | bionic                   | source`

but if you applied upgrades to the system, I'd expect the following version

`grub2 | 2.02-2ubuntu8.25        | bionic-security          | source`

If you *release-upgraded* to Ubuntu 20.04, I'd expect the following version to exist on the system

`grub2 | 2.04-1ubuntu26.15       | focal-updates            | source`

The URL I provided contains all the detail you wanted; I just opted to use the same input provided from a terminal command as I find it easier to copy/paste from.  Note:  I've assumed *amd64* architecture; though in this case it doesn't matter (but *i386* for example isn't supported in *focal* (20.04) thus has no listing there).

Comment: Also maybe of note.... I used the term "*initial media* meaning Ubuntu 18.04 LTS media; if you used Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS media, through to Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS media the installed version can vary as it'll be whatever was in -updates at the time. My use of "*initial media*" was to refer to the initial media on actual release; not the re-spins.   If I wanted to know what version was on a later ISO (eg. 18.04.3 for example which is an older ISO) that wasn't updated, I'd look at the *manifest* for that version ISO.

Comment: If of interest; the command I use is `rmadison grub2` to get the results I posted... I find it very handy given I'm usually running the *development* release which isn't included on the URL I usually post here.  By default that script isn't installed (*devscripts*) but is easily installed.